# Etimología de "tuno"

Tags: etimología, dle

El Diccionario de la Lengua, en [**tuno, na**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=avLh9e7) recoge (negrita mía):

> **La forma f.**, del fr. *tune* 'hospicio de mendigos', 'limosna', y este de *[Roi de] Thunes* '[Rey de] Túnez', nombre dado al jefe de los vagabundos franceses en memoria del duque del Bajo Egipto, esto es, el jefe de los gitanos de París en 1427.
>   
>   1. adj. Pícaro, tunante. U. t. c. s.
>   2. m. Componente de una tuna (‖ grupo musical de estudiantes).
>   3. f. Grupo de estudiantes que forman un conjunto musical.
>   4. f. Vida libre y vagabunda.

Aparte de ser una curiosa etimología, me llama la atención que hace referencia exclusivamente a la **forma femenina**, es decir, a **tuna**. ¿Tiene **tuno** otro origen?

Comment: Parece que solo dan el origen de tuna, el conjunto musical.

Comment: @aparente001 Corominas trae la misma etimología y matiza que "**Tuna 'estudiantina' es desarrollo posterior propiamente español.**"

Comment: Me da a mí la sensación de que no debe tener mayor recorrido: dado _tuna_ para designar un grupo, se pasó a llamar a cualquiera de sus miembros como _tuno_. Lo que sí veo es que _tunante_ viene del verbo [_tunar_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=auPerx1):  _Andar vagando en vida libre_.

Comment: Curioso, según la tercera acepción los Beatles son una tuna, ya que todos eran estudiantes (el mayor tenía 16 años) cuando se conocieron y formaron el grupo.

Comment: @fedorqui *tunante* viene del verbo *tunar*, pero el verbo *tunar* viene de *tuno*, así que volvemos a lo mismo.

Answer (score 1):

La etimología hace referencia a la forma femenina porque su significado original, según el *Diccionario de Autoridades*, era en femenino:

> TUNA. [...] vida holgazana, libre, y vagamunda.

De aquí se derivan (y no al revés) otras palabras como *tunar* 'andar vagando en vida holgazana y libre', y *tunante* 'el que tuna'.

No da explicación sobre su origen, cosa que sí hace Corominas, aunque como verás es exactamente la misma que aparece en el DLE:

> Del antiguo argot francés *tune* 'hospicio de los mendigos', 'limosna', 1628, propte. 'la mendicidad'. Éste deriva del nombre del *Roi de Thunes*, 1628, o jefe de los vagabundos franceses, a quien se dio este nombre de 'Rey de Túnez', por alusión al de 'Duque del Bajo Egipto' que se hacía dar el jefe de los gitanos, cuando sus bandas llegaron por primera vez a París en 1427.

En la [web del CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/tune) se comenta sobre la palabra *tune* en francés que su etimología es rechazada por algunos, que proponen que deriva del galo-romano **tutina*, derivado de *tutari* 'proteger; protegerse (de un peligro: hambre, frío)', de ahí la noción de limosna que consiste esencialmente en pan, o en épocas más modernas en una moneda.